# How to check all specific file type files are copied into a directory?

Tags: bash

I've tried to compare specific file type (like .txt) and a specific directory by using the diff function but it doesn't turn out right. Can I get some help here?

```sh
backup=$(find . -name "*.text" -type f)
backup2=$(find /home/user/Desktop/backupfile -name "*.text" -type f)

diff -rq $backup $backup2
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below, using a for loop comparing the files in both locations (if found) :

```
for f in ($find . -type f -name "*.text")
do
   name=$(basename "$f")
   if [ -f /home/user/Desktop/backupfile/"$name" ]
   then
       diff -rq "$f" /home/user/Desktop/backupfile/"$name"
   else
       echo match of "$f" not found under /home/user/Desktop/backupfile/
done
```